Why is the kabalat hatorah at Purim needed?
The Gemara (Shabbos 88a) says that at Har Sinai Bnei Yisrael might have only accepted the Torah out of coercion, which would enable them to say that their acceptance was not halachically valid. Therefore, Rava adds that they re-accepted it, with free will, at the time of the Purim story.
Why is this explanation needed when Moshe already reaffirmed their covenant with G-d in Parshat Nitzavim?

Tosafot says that even by the reaffirmation of the covenant in the plains of Moav it was considered coerced because

ע"פ הדיבור היה
it was by means of a command (from Hashem)

The Noda BiYehuda explains that a Divine command is akin to a physical coercion. Therefore, as the rest of the Tosafot explains, by the events of Purim,

קבלו מדעתם מאהבת הנס
they accepted it willingly out of love of the miracle

Note: the Noda BiYehuda argues on this and goes on a very long discussion about how we can still prove that there was coercion also in Moav, and concludes it's a machloket between Rabbi Yossi and the Rabbanan. I think the overall summary is:

Some hold, based on this tosafot, that this is a case of coercion because the holding up of the mountain as a barrel over their heads was a demonstration that Hashem could always do that, so it implies continual coercion.
He asks why holding the mountain was necessary when it is known from the time of Creation that the world would revert to nothing if the Jews didn't accept Torah
He answers that that condition was only on the world up until the 6th of Sivan, at which point the world was established forever by Hashem. Therefore we are just left with the problem of the implied coercion of the mountain
He then argues that, according to those who hold the Torh was given on the 7th of Sivan, that the holding of the mountain wasn't coercion for the future, it was only for the fear of immediate refusal after going through the intense experience of Sinai on the 7th of Sinai
Therefore there was no coercion at Mo'av, according to this opinion (Rabbi Yossi) and therefore no need for reacceptance in Achashverosh's time
Therefore the opinion that we had a reacceptance at Purim holds we got the Torah on the 6th of Sivan (Rabbanan)
He then diverts to a discussion about the Torah being given chatumah (as a sealed document, Rabbi Eliezer HaModai) vs megillah megillah (scroll by scroll, Rabbi Yehoshua), mentions the wider discussions of these tannaim about this issue, and whether the Megilla is Divinely inspired, and then aligns the views there with the opinions of Rabbi Yossi and Rabbanan above, respectively


Let me know if you'd like me to summarise the Tziyun

If you could, I'd appreciate it.

@Banana done, it is very long, and some points I couldn't quite fully understand, but I did my best to summarise the main points

Thank you so much!
